# Como mejorar la indexacion en mi buscador interno

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una cuestión.

Tengo un buscador interno en mi pagina web, el cual necesito mejorarlo al momento de arrojar resultados.

Lo que busco hacer es que si el usuario omite palabras o escribe mal alguna, o en caso de que la palabra tenga acento, siempre le arroje un resultado,que la pagina no quede vacía.

tengo de ejemplo la siguiente consulta:

```
<?php                
require 'conexion.php';
$busca=$_POST["busca"];
echo "<center>Su palabra de busqueda fue: $busca</center>";
$sql=mysql_query("select  * from producto  where tipo like '%$busca%' or 
modelo like '%$busca%' or marca like '%$busca%' or area like '%$busca%'
or area1 like '%$busca%'
or area2 like '%$busca%'
or area3 like '%$busca%'
or area4 like '%$busca%'
or area5 like '%$busca%'
order by id_producto desc");        
while($res=  mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: tendrías que configurar la DB con full text search y modificar la consulta hay varios ejemplos en https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=full+text+search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el cli `mysql` o una utilidad de tipo phpMyAdmin agregas un index [`FULLTEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) a la tabla indicando los campos sobre los cuales se creará el índice.

```
ALTER TABLE producto 
ADD FULLTEXT (tipo, modelo, marca, area, area1, area2, area3, area4, area5);
```

Luego la consulta te quedaría algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM producto 
WHERE MATCH( tipo, modelo, marca, area, area1, area2, area3, area4, area5 )
AGAINST ('$busca');
```

Comment: Ah sido de gran ayuda tu comentario, solo tengo una duda esta consulta la hago directo en mi BD: 
**ALTER TABLE producto ADD FULLTEXT (tipo, modelo, marca, area, area1, area2, area3, area4, area5);**

la otra supongo va directo en mi código
solo tengo esa cuestion

Comment: el `ALTER` lo haces sobre la DB una única vez pues es para agregarle un index a la tabla, luego el `SELECT` es cómo quedaría la consulta en el código

Comment: Que tal, hice lo que me comentaste, yo le coloque el ALTER TABLE a las 57 tablas que ocupo para mi buscador, me dejo llenar de 16 en 16, y al momento de poner una consulta en XAMMP me arrojo el siguiente error:
#1191 - No puedo encontrar índice FULLTEXT correspondiendo a la lista de columnas
y al momento de colocar la consulta en el código me arroja un error al ejecutar alguna consulta.

Comment: cada índice `FULLTEXT` es para un conjunto de columnas, si luego buscas por menos columnas tendrás que crear otro índice `FULLTEXT` o incluir todas las columnas del índice que agregaste a la tabla. para evitar dañar tus datos, hacé copia de seguridad y empezá por una tabla, una vez que lo tenés funcionando vas por otra tabla.